# Html Aglity pack extra <A> tag

Tags: html-agility-pack

The extra `<A>` in the following causes selectnode() to return too many elements. How can I remove the extra characters?

```
<DIV align=center><STRONG><A><A class=white 
      href="javascript: event_info = openWin('/events/search/index_results.cfm?action=plan&amp;event_number=2013292001&amp;cde_comp_group=CONF&amp;cde_comp_type=&amp;NEW_END_DATE1>=&amp;key_stkhldr_event=&amp;mixed_breed=N', 'eventinfo', 'width=800,height=600,toolbar=1,location=0>,directories=0,status=0,menuBar=0,scrollBars=1,resizable=1' ); event_info.focus()"><STRONG>Labrador 
      Retriever Club of the Piedmont</STRONG></A> </STRONG></DIV
```

>

Answer (score 1):

You could select only those `<a>` tags, which have e.g. `href` attribute set:

```
var doc = new HtmlDocument();
doc.LoadHtml(html);
var anchors = doc.DocumentNode
    .SelectNodes("//a[@href]")
    .ToList();

foreach (var anchor in anchors)
{
    //process your node here
}
```